# Update .htaccess to allow specific directory link to work without having to go to index

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm using the follow code in my .htaccess file to remove the need for the file extension .html on my site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This is all working great. However I have a subdirectory with an index file which you currently have to access via /subdirectory/index/ . I would like to target this subdirectory in my .htaccess file to allow it so that I can write /subdirectory/ and it still load the index page.

Currently if I go to /subdirectory/ I get the following error:

```
You don't have permission to access /subdirectory/.html on this server.
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another rewrite condition, to test weather the given path is an existing directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: @probablybest Glad to have helped :)